# "Unable to find all tx inputs"

Tags: raw-transaction

I've created a transaction using "bitcoinjs-lib".

Here is the hash:

```
01000000013f3e32e0b436f37d6c67265dd0cb71053fe6b6f9cee12efbe52065071215d37b000000006a47304402203dc1f1d173ac8eaa059ef6f703793d16c98a33f1d6e2b6b83b894517041fdc08022065e57c6ad4c3f371348334b6aa27188ce4719f6278dc18003f60d4081b423c2401210273abe13a1fefd8663f7deeb4e755ad8753481fc6204b24e244835207edcbb760ffffffff02e8030000000000001976a91414c50581bac21c1fa611f906db135736d87e4c5088ac54820100000000001976a91463978c3bc763ceb4981d6992224d4b0c2892652888ac00000000
```

Here is the value of this hash.

```
{
   "lock_time":0,
   "size":225,
   "inputs":[
      {
         "prev_out":{
            "index":0,
            "hash":"7bd31512076520e5fb2ee1cef9b6e63f0571cbd05d26676c7df336b4e0323e3f"
         },
         "script":"47304402203dc1f1d173ac8eaa059ef6f703793d16c98a33f1d6e2b6b83b894517041fdc08022065e57c6ad4c3f371348334b6aa27188ce4719f6278dc18003f60d4081b423c2401210273abe13a1fefd8663f7deeb4e755ad8753481fc6204b24e244835207edcbb760"
      }
   ],
   "version":1,
   "vin_sz":1,
   "hash":"a85b07d647f728986687933f30db758b545144b34e9110d78355b2c11efc8423",
   "vout_sz":2,
   "out":[
      {
         "script_string":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 14c50581bac21c1fa611f906db135736d87e4c50 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
         "address":"12tpY8cF2bfTUzTQSZjwhRZ2k33RGNKzpg",
         "value":1000,
         "script":"76a91414c50581bac21c1fa611f906db135736d87e4c5088ac"
      },
      {
         "script_string":"OP_DUP OP_HASH160 63978c3bc763ceb4981d6992224d4b0c28926528 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
         "address":"1A5bSiXqBBt4rSani8UHaAV4314pU8poN9",
         "value":98900,
         "script":"76a91463978c3bc763ceb4981d6992224d4b0c2892652888ac"
      }
   ]
}
```

Blockchain gives the error `"Unable to find all tx inputs"`.

Why is this (and how do I fix it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading correctly, your input transaction is  `7bd31512076520e5fb2ee1cef9b6e63f0571cbd05d26676c7df336b4e0323e3f`.  This transaction is [not found](https://blockchain.info/search?search=7bd31512076520e5fb2ee1cef9b6e63f0571cbd05d26676c7df336b4e0323e3f) by a search on blockchain.info.  I would guess one of the following is true:

- The transaction id is incorrect
- The transaction was never broadcast
- The transaction was broadcast, but was never confirmed, and so much time has passed that  blockchain.info stopped keeping track of it.

So, check that the id is correct, and if it is, try (re)broadcasting the transaction.

Comment: Ah, actually, it's here: https://blockchain.info/unspent?active=1H7PdtHQW94eYaeor2c7VBXCXNw1oomvPm&format=&confirmations=1
I just took the `tx_hash` value, which is the ID, right?

Comment: Interestingly, searching for the big-endian version succeeds.  This is odd because my understanding is that the [usual convention](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#hash-byte-order) is to use little-endian in RPC calls and similar "external" contexts.  Maybe someone more familiar with blockchain.info can help us understand.  Anyway, you probably want to resolve this, because if there's a similar issue with your output addresses, you could wind up with unspendable outputs.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! Got it. It worked before I actually read your reply and yeah, now thinking about it, it's strange that big endian isn't the default!